# NGINX - How to redirect '/<param>' to index.php?page=<param>

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I read a lot of questions here in StackOverflow and I also tried  the answered solutions, but I still can't achieve what I need.

I have the following simple routing code written in PHP:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo "<section id='content' class='container'>";

if ( isset($page) )
{
    switch($page)
    {
        case "guides":
            require_once("v/pages/guides/index.php");
            break;
        case "error-list-dpto":
            require_once("v/pages/error-list/error-list-dpto.php");
            break;
        //other cases here...
    }
}
echo "</section>";
```

And I have the simple nginx configuration below:

```
server {  
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root  /app/mylogs;
    server_name localhost;

    index index.php;

    location /(.*) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$1 =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
    }
}
```

I would like to access something like "http://example.com/guides" and making the $page variable receive the "guides" word as value.

But my NGINX code isn't working. When I try to access the address above I get a 404 from NGINX.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I need using the following NGINX conf file lines:

```
rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```